# TypeError:Tensor objects are not iterable when using the dataset.iterator

Tags: tensorflow

With the codes below, I want to try the tf.data.TFRecordDataset using cifar-10.But I got error and stuck on it for hours.

My codes:

```
import tensorflow as tf

    def parser(serialized_example):
        features = tf.parse_single_example(
            serialized_example,
            features={
                'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string), 
                'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                'channels': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
                     }
        )

        decoded_image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
        decoded_image = tf.reshape(decoded_image, [32, 32, 3])
        label = features['label']
        return decoded_image, label


    train_files = ['./test_data/test.tfrecords']
    datasets = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(train_files)
    datesets = datasets.map(parser)
    datasets = datasets.shuffle(1000).batch(20)
    datasets = datasets.repeat(10)
    iterator = datasets.make_initializable_iterator()
    image_batch, label_batch = iterator.get_next()
```

load the cifar-10 :

```
def load_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fo:
        data = pickle.load(fo, encoding='latin1')
    return data

def get_data(filename):
    data_raw = load_data(filename)
    data = data_raw['data']
    labels = data_raw['labels']

    red = data[:, :1024].reshape((10000, 32, 32))
    green = data[:, 1024:2048].reshape((10000, 32, 32))
    blue = data[:, 2048:].reshape((10000, 32, 32))

    graph_array = np.asarray((red, green, blue)).swapaxes(0, 1).swapaxes(1, 3).swapaxes(1, 2)

    return graph_array, np.asarray(labels)
```

and here are codes for saving to tfrecords:

```
image, label = get_data('test_batch')
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('./test_data/test.tfrecords')
    for index in range(image.shape[0]):
        image_raw = image[index].tostring()
        example = tf.train.Example(
            features=tf.train.Features(
                feature={
                    'image_raw': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[image_raw])),
                    'label': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[label[index]])),
                    'width': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[image.shape[1]])),
                    'height': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[image.shape[2]])),
                    'channels': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[image.shape[3]]))
                }
            )
        )
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
writer.close()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Jason_F\Documents\Python Scripts\Nets\Fisrt_for_test\train.py", line 72, in <module>
tf.app.run()
    File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
_sys.exit(main(argv))
    File "C:\Users\Jason_F\Documents\Python Scripts\Nets\Fisrt_for_test\train.py", line 69, in main
train()
    File "C:\Users\Jason_F\Documents\Python Scripts\Nets\Fisrt_for_test\train.py", line 37, in train
image_batch, label_batch = iterator.get_next()
    File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 436, in __iter__
"Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not "
    TypeError: Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.
```

When I check the output_shape of datasets like this:

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaR5B.png)

It seems the func map didn't work at all.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You have a typo: `datesets = datasets.map(parser)`.

Comment: @xdurch0 oh, yes it is! Thank you very much! I've never thought about this, a little mistake but also a big problem.Thanks again!